# I can't implement a delay on my characters dash

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make my characters dash not go on forever but have a certain delay and then be able to dash again. My character will decide to have the delay sometimes then other times it will continuously dash without a delay when I click the key. Can anyone help me solve this? Thanks.

edit someone told me to start using coroutines but I am sort of unsure how this works, i edited the code to use "yield" but I am unclear on how that works too. can someone tell me if this is correct for what I want and how to fix it? Thanks

```
if (hasTeleportedRecently == false)
        {
            transform.position = transform.position + transportVector;
            hasTeleportedRecently = true;
            yield return 3;
            hasTeleportedRecently = false;
        }
```

Comment: Look into Coroutines...

Comment: coroutines and invoke are both powerful and uncomplicated.  If you head to youtube you will find much on them in video form, or can google and find many examples.  You can also use c# tasks if you want, but you may find them a little more confusing.

Comment: If you have a new question, it's ok to post a separate one. Do not edit your question into a different one, especially don't remove the problem's description and your code which caused it. This action invalidates answers and confuses people.

Comment: I’ve rolled back your question to the point at which the answers were written. The goal of this site is to create a collection of questions and answers for future visitors to benefit from too. Please use a new post for new questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without coroutines. Make a field of type `float` where you store time when teleport becomes available again, and compare current time with it when player attempts to teleport:

```
float now = Time.time;
if (now >= teleportAvailableAt) {
    transform.position += transportVector;
    teleportAvailableAt = now + 3f;
}
```

Hint:

Don't compare booleans with `true` or `false`. Omit `== true` altogether and replace `== false` with the `!` operator. It's shorter and less prone to bugs (you can accidentally write `if (flag = false) ...` - you *assign* false here and it still compiles)

Comment: I am getting the error get_time is not allowed to be called from monobehavior constructer. Call in it an Awake or Start Instead. How can I fix this?

Comment: @JackHengen You should not declare constructor for your `MonoBehaviour`s. They should be attached to `GameObject`s by `AddComponent`, and then their `Awake` function is called if present (and `Start` on the first frame if it's active). For more info, ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/tim12332000/TimUnityUtility/blob/master/Assets/ScheduleHelper/ScheduleHelper.cs

Use that , for example , make a task delay 3 seconed.

```
hasTeleportedRecently = true;
ScheduleHelper.Instance.DelayDo(()=> {hasTeleportedRecently = false;},3f);
```